# Magnolia CMS Jboss Server Configuration (Middleware Task)

Tags: jboss, content-management-system, middleware, magnolia, server-configuration

I am new with Magnolia CMS and assigned task to list down activity which needs to be performed from Middleware prospective.

The Application WAR file will be provided by development team which we will deploy on JBOSS/WildFly server. Is there something specific we have to configure on server for Magnolia CMS OR We can treat the WAR file as normal WAR file deployment.

I am looking answer from server configuration prospective.

Thanks
Mayank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some stuff have to be configured and the following link should help in that case [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Deploying+a+WAR+on+Wildfly+(JBoss+EAP)+application+server). Also it depends on the Wildfly version, I believe this one targets the newer version but the old ones are slightly different. Perhaps this may do at that case [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS54/Wildfly+(JBoss+AS)+configuration).

Comment: Thanks for guide . I have successfully deployed and run magnolia on WildFly server. Only server config chages were required to support Magnolia features.